# Selecting columns based on matching/fuzzy matching value of two columns

Tags: r, record-linkage

I have data frame `df1` with columns `"Year"` and `"Agent"`:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(1999, 1999, 1998), Agent = list(c("abn-amro-nv", "suntrust banks", "wachovia"), c("jp morgan", "abn-amro-nv"), c("ba-corp", "boston bks", "nbd"))), .Names = c("Year", "Agent"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

#df1
Year                                   Agent
1999   abn-amro-nv, suntrust banks, wachovia
1999                  jp morgan, abn-amro-nv
1998                ba-corp, boston bks, nbd
```

I have another data frame `df2` which has 5 columns `"Rank"`, `"Arrangers"`, `"Share"`, `"Issues"` and `"Year"`, as following:

```
df2 <- structure(list(Rank = 1:3, Arranger = c("jp morgan", "boston-bank", "suntrust bk"), Share = c(1.2, 1.8, 2.1), Issues = c(7L, 4L, 3L), Year = c(1999L, 1998L, 1999L)), .Names = c("Rank", "Arranger", "Share", "Issues", "Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

#df2
Rank    Arranger         Share    Issues    Year
 1      jp morgan        1.2       7        1999
 2      boston-bank      1.8       4        1998
 3      suntrust bk      2.1       3        1999
```

I need to match `"Agent"` and `"Year"` of `df1` with `"Arranger"` and `"Year"` of `df2` and select 3 columns from `df2` such as `"Rank"`, `"Share"`, `"Issues"`.
Matching of `"Agent"` of `df1` with `"Arranger"` of `df2` will be fuzzy matching. It's because they are not exactly same.

My original data frames are very large just for your information.

Following is my code:

```
library(stringdist)

leadrep <- matrix(ncol=3, nrow=length(df1$Agent))

for (i in 1:length(df1$Agent)) {

  for (j in 1:length(df2$Arrangers)) {

      if ((ain(df2$Arrangers[j], df1$Agent[[i]], maxDist=0.3, 
      method="jw")) == 'TRUE' & (df1$Year[i] == df2$Year[j])){             

         leadrep[i,] <-  df2[j, c('Rank', 'Mkt.Share', 'NumberofIssues')]

      }

  }
}
```

In the code, `leadrep` is matrix which I created. So that I can populate in the `for loop`. I used `stringdist` package and `ain` function to do fuzzy matching. And I used two `for loop` and `if` to compare the strings and year.

The above code works but it's taking too long time to get the results since my data frames are large. I really think that my approach above is not an efficient. It would be a great help if someone provides me a better alternative to my existing code.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: what errors did you get?

Comment: `Error: unexpected '&' in:
"    if ((ain(df2$Arrangers[j], df1$Agent[[i]], maxDist=0.3, 
          method="jw")) == 'TRUE') &"`                                                                                                                                                                                                  Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"

Comment: this question might be closed on account of there being a simple typo of an extra `(`.

Comment: As I can see, there are 3 opening  brackets and 3 closing brackets before "&" in if. Where is extra ( ?.

Comment: Look what happens when `a <-1; b <-2; if (((a == 1))) & (b ==2) { print("this works") }`, then try `if ((((a == 1))) & (b ==2)) { print("this works")}`

Comment: Thanks. a <-1; b <-2; if ((a == 1) & (b ==2)) { print("this works") }

Comment: I closed both if conditions in bracket and it worked just like above.

Comment: @shayaa Code is taking too long time to get the results. I do not think this is an efficient code/method to get result. Maybe I should edit my question and request a better alternative to my existing approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach uses `foreach` instead of your two nested `for` loops, which should make your computation much faster on large data frames. See [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-wonders-of-foreach/) for a nice overview of the package. You should also look at the vignettes.

```
library(foreach)
library(stringdist)

match.cond <- function(ij, df1, df2) {                                   ## 1.
  i = floor((ij-1) / nrow(df2)) + 1
  j = ij - (i-1) * nrow(df2)
  if ((ain(df2$Arranger[j], df1$Agent[[i]], maxDist=0.3, 
       method="jw")) == 'TRUE' & (df1$Year[i] == df2$Year[j])){
    return(df2[j, c('Rank', 'Share', 'Issues')])
  }
}

leadrep <- foreach(ij = 1:(nrow(df1)*nrow(df2)), .combine=rbind) %do%    ## 2.
  match.cond(ij, df1, df2)
```

Notes:

1. `match.cond` is your match condition encapsulated into a *kernel* function that will be *vectorized* by `foreach` over all pairings of rows from `df1` and `df2`. Its inputs are `ij`, which is an index to the pairings, and the two data frames. Within `match.cond`:

   - `ij` is converted to the row indices `i` for `df1` and `j` for `df2`
   - Your condition is evaluated, and if the condition is met,
   - The columns from `df2` for the matched row is returned.
2. This is the `foreach` call.

   - We loop over the indices `ij` from `1` to `nrow(df1)*nrow(df2)`, which enumerates all pairings of rows from `df1` and `df2` and `%do%` the `match.cond` function. Note that this is all one line.
   - The `.combine=rbind` argument states that we want to gather all results from `match.cond` and bind them as rows.
   - This returns the data frame `leadrep`

I've tested on your data, which I've `dput`:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(1999, 1999, 1998), Agent = list(c("abn-amro-nv", 
"suntrust banks", "wachovia"), c("jp morgan", "abn-amro-nv"), 
c("ba-corp", "boston bks", "nbd"))), .Names = c("Year", "Agent"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Rank = 1:3, Arranger = c("jp morgan", "boston-bank", 
"suntrust bk"), Share = c(1.2, 1.8, 2.1), Issues = c(7L, 4L, 
3L), Year = c(1999L, 1998L, 1999L)), .Names = c("Rank", "Arranger", 
"Share", "Issues", "Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

which gives me the desired result:

```
print(leadrep)
##   Rank Share Issues
##3     3   2.1      3
##2     1   1.2      7
##21    2   1.8      4
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. My current code is taking too much time. So you approach helps me in reducing computation time. Thanks a bunch again.

Comment: Actually, I had a slight error in my original post. In calculating `i` and `j`, I should use `now(df2)` instead of `now(df1)`. This will matter if they are not the same, which was not the case with the test data. I've already made the edits to the post.